# Disable root password via ansible-playbook on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ansible

I'm currently trying to disable root login for an ubuntu 18.04 machine via ansible playbook.

If I ssh in I know I can type `passwd -l root` to do this.  Is this the way to do it via ansible playbook?

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Disable root login
    raw: passwd -l root
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Quoting from the parameter [*password*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#parameter-password) of the Ansible module *user*:

> To create a disabled account on Linux systems, set this to '!' or '*'.

This is the same as *`passwd -l`*. Quoting from *man* [*passwd*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html):

> -l, --lock Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a password by changing it to a value that matches no possible encrypted value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning of the password). Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key).

For example,

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Disable root login
    user:
      name: root
      password: '!'
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

- The same should be achieved by the parameter [*password_lock*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#parameter-password_lock) of the Ansible module *user*:

> Lock the password (usermod -L, ...

The only difference is the utility. Quoting from *man* [*usermod*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/usermod.8.html):

> -L, --lock Lock a user's password. This puts a '!' in front of the encrypted password, effectively disabling the password. You can't use this option with -p or -U.

For example,

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Disable root login
    user:
      name: root
      password_lock: true
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

- Before you delete the root's password make sure the Ansible remote user can escalate privileges by *sudo*. For example,

```bash
shell> cat /etc/sudoers
...
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```